# Removing an item from an arrayList in java

Tags: java, netbeans, collections, arraylist

I have a program that takes input from a file, saves each word in the file as a token and then adds each token to an array list.

The problem is that the arrayList comes up as for example ["cat","dog"," "," ","bird"], and I don't want the spaces in the arrayList.

And the file that is read is set up as shown below:

```
cat dog


bird
```

It is obvious that it is the blank lines cause the spaces, but the blank lines are necessary.

Anyway, my code is below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class NewMain{

public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Filename");

        //Get the object of datainputstream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        List<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
       while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        String [] tokens = strLine.split("\\s+");
        String [] words = tokens;
        for(String word : words){
            listOfWords.add(word);
            System.out.print(word);
            System.out.print(" ");      
        } 
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
       System.out.println(listOfWords);

        List<String> space = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] spaces = {" "};
        space.addAll(Arrays.asList(spaces));

        editList(listOfWords,space);

        System.out.println(listOfWords);
in.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());    
    }  
}

public static void editList(Collection<String> list1, Collection<String> list2){
    Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){         
       if(list2.contains(it.next())) {
                it.remove();
            }  
       }
}
}
```

The `String[] spaces = {" "};` should remove the blank spaces, as I have tested it by removing spaces from an non-file arrayList. And the strange thing is that if I change it to `String[] spaces = {"cat"};` it will remove cat from the arrayList.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your for loop add an if condition:

```
for(String word : words){
            if(!word.equals(""))  /* OR if( (word.length > 0) )*/  {
            listOfWords.add(word);
            System.out.print(word);
            System.out.print(" ");   
           }   
        }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks

Comment: `word.length() == 0` is more reasonable than comparing to the empty string. See my answer.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Either way..! I have updated the ans. The main point to make OP aware of where he need to add a condition. then its upto him , which form of condition suits him. Thanks for suggestion though :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is quite obvious. A possible solution is to use this:

`strLine = br.readLine().trim()`

then implement your `while` loop as:

`while (strLine != null && !strLine.isEmpty()) { //do stuff }`

Comment: I consider this just a workaround for the particular case of *empty lines*. Assuming that he would split on `;`, and had a line such as `word;word;;;word`, he would still get two *empty words*. It definitely is not incorrect. Sometimes you want to filter empty lines, but keep empty words.

Comment: Yeah, well, this depends on the goal of the program. In such a case, after implementing the while loop as stated, he can easily check if each token is empty too and then process it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing *empty* strings - since you split via the whitespace pattern `\s+`, you will *not* have `" "` in your list, but `""`:

```
String[] spaces = {""};
```

But instead of removing them afterwards, **don't add them in the first place**!

```
if (word.length() == 0) continue;
listOfWords.add(word);
```

(and add any similar filters you need!)

This is **not just simpler**. It is also much more efficient. Removing an element from an array list costs `O(n)`. So the complexity of the code you used for filtering is `O(n^2)` (you could get this down to `O(n)` by copying into a second list). Not adding the elements in the first place is essentially for free; your parsing will even become a bit faster this way - still in `O(n)`, but faster than filter in a second step.

Comment: Also works, thanks. This is only a small part of my program, and I am dealing with large files that aren't create by me, so it's too much work to remove all the spaces for each file manually. But thanks

Comment: With "don't add them in the first place", I was referring to the code where you `listOfWords.add(word);` them to the list; not to the original data!

Comment: I also added an explanation of why it is faster to filter on parsing than post-processing the list. If your files are this large, you should notice the difference.